Trying To Recreate "Neo Vision" from The Matrix Reloaded In Geometry Nodes
I have the basis I think for this effect, but I'm running into trouble getting my instanced characters (In this case a 0 and 1 for the moment) to move individually both along the object they're assigned to (In this case a watch) and drop off of the object to then fade out or scale down to nothing. I also have them accumulate over time but not die out and re-accumulate like I'd like them to.
I'd like the characters to move in one direction around whatever object they are assigned to, so far I've only been able to get them to move all at once without random assignment and not along the objects in the collection and to scale individually but only at the same time.
UPDATED 2:

Update: I found this tutorial which lead me on how to create the cascading and changing text on curves, I then used this nodes setup to map the curves onto my watch object. I'm running into a few issues, the first being with the Raycasting, it requires projection at an angle when I want it to surround objects completely. The second issue is that all my text is facing upwards in one direction, when I want them to rotate and wrap around whatever object they're assigned to. Finally, I have this annoying bug in the middle of my wrap object where a bunch of characters are stacked on top of each other and I can't find a way to make them go away. I still haven't found a way to cause the characters to drop off of the object and fade away, that might be asking too much from geometry nodes.
Update 2: I found another post and implemented the nodes necessary to go after the curves in the Geo Nodes setup to rotate based on my object, and that does work however I'm still having trouble covering my entire object with the Raycast as well as the duplicate objects still accumulating in the center.
Additional Nodes To Rotate Instances

